# android:screenOrientation="portrait" ignored on a Nexus 5x running Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am getting reports that my supposedly portrait app can be rotated to landscape mode on a Nexus 5X running Marshmallow. I don't have one to test on but why is this happening? Here is my activity in the manifest:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".app.MainActivity_"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
    </activity>
```

Comment: you can try in emulator

Comment: works for me in emulator

Comment: can you try `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` on the OnCreate section of the target activity?

Comment: I'd do this in `onResume()` though

Comment: Akis_Tfs could be correct. I´ve read about some posts that some devices ignore that attribute in manifest, but accept it programmatically...

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas do you mean that you can reproduce the problem in an emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change your `tragetSDKVersion` from `Marshmallow` to `Lollipop`.

It worked for me.

Comment: My target version is 21

Comment: Ok, May be some different thing causing this issue, bad I assumed. My case was different. Have you tried setting it runtime as said in other comments, that should work I think. @J.K.

Answer (score -1):

You must use this for the Activity!

```
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

and for the whole application you must use this code which will force the orientation not to be landscape

```
<application 
  android:debuggable="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:configChanges="orientation"       
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: `android:configChanges` has nothing to do with this.